# OSMDroid PathOverlay not appearing

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I'm trying to add a path overlay to an OSMDroid map and it is not appearing. What am I missing?

**Update:**

I figured out it has something to do with the tile size. I set the size to 512 even though the tiles are 256 otherwise the maps are too small to read on high pixel density screens. If I change the size to 256, the path displays. If I change it back to 512, it doesn't display.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // set this to 256 for actual tile size, 512 to show larger and cause PathOverlay to not be displayed
    int tileSize = 512; 

    private MapView mapView;

    // area of offline tiles
    double north = 40.739063;
    double south =  40.708361;
    double west  =  -73.967171;
    double east  =  -73.936272;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // center of offline tiles
        double centerlat = (double) ((north+south)/2);
        double centerlon = (double) ((west+east)/2);

        // copy tiles to sd location for offline map
        putMapOnSD();

        // create mapView and show layout
        mapView = new MapView(this,tileSize);
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams mapViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.addView(mapView, mapViewLayoutParams);
        setContentView(layout);

        // set map to use offline tiles and display
        mapView.setTileSource  (new XYTileSource ("tiles", ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode, 13, 17, tileSize, ".png", "http://127.0.0.1")); 
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
        mapView.setClickable(false);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(centerlat,centerlon));

        // show pathOverlay
        PathOverlay pathOverlay = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
        pathOverlay.addPoint(new GeoPoint(centerlat,centerlon));
        centerlat += 0.005;
        pathOverlay.addPoint(new GeoPoint(centerlat,centerlon));
        centerlon += 0.005;
        pathOverlay.addPoint(new GeoPoint(centerlat,centerlon));
        pathOverlay.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(pathOverlay);

        // refresh map, is this needed?
        mapView.invalidate();
    }


    // this copies the offline tiles to the proper location for OSMDroid to use them offline
    private void putMapOnSD() {
        // see GitHub for this
    }
}
```

Get the full project on GitHub. https://github.com/tomkincaid/PathExample

I solved this problem by using @2x tiles from Cloudmade, so I didn't have to use the 512 pixel size for high density screens. The basic issue still exists though in case anyone wants to investigate.

Comment: if larger tile size couse path overlay disappier, you might have to play wiht your geo coordinates increa either ther difference or size :) once this worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to add a `Paint` with stroke to `PathOverlay`.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(155);
paint.setColor(Color.argb(205, 178, 255, 255));
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
pathOverlay.setPaint(paint);
```

UPDATE:
I think, the main reason why your path is not appearing is directly related to `Tile Size` parameter. Because while drawing the pathOVerlay, all projections and line calculations are based on this parameter. So, if you set it to something which is not the actual size of the tile, then computation will fail and not show the overlay path.

Comment: Still not displaying.

Comment: Since I used OSMDroid map with path overlays before, I will ask you to post the whole code of your map activity so I can help on it .

Comment: Thanks Tim. The code has a lot of extra stuff in it. I will have to clean it up to make the example clear. I have found that Cloudmade provides tiles at 2x so it actually solves the problem. I can use their tiles at 256.

Comment: I posted the code of an example project and put the whole thing on GitHub.